# Laravel 5.4 update method does not update

Tags: laravel-5, patch

I have this route:
Route::resource('my-account', 'ProfileController');

I have this method in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
        DB::enableQuerylog();

        $user->update([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'phone' => $request->phone
        ]);

        dd(\DB::getQuerylog());
}
```

I have this form:

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/my-account/'. $user->id) }}">

    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group" id="firstNameDiv">

        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ $user->first_name }}">

        <span class="help-block" id="firstNameError"></span>

    </div>
```

When I submit the form the first name is not being updated in the table.

If I try dd($request->first_name) I see the name that I entered.

The DB log returns an empty array like this: [], why is it not updating?

Comment: what do you got if you `dd($user)`? maybe the `$user` instance is not what you think it is?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the $fillable in your User model

```
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone'];
```

[Read more in: Mass Assignment Eloquent Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 1):

if u don't use created_at and updated_at in the table you should disable them  using :
public $timestamps = false;

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `dd` as the first thing to be executed in your method to be sure that it gets fired. At least that's how I do it every time something seems not to be doing anything.

Next is, why are you doing `update` without `where`? Unless you want to update all the records, you should have `where()` in your query.

Also btw, not sure about this... shouldn't you be injecting your model in the constructor instead?

Either try something like this

```
$user = User::find($id) // or in your case $user->find($id);
$user->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
$user->save();
```

Or

```
$user->where('id', $id)->update(['firstname' => $request->input('firstname')]);
```

Comment: Thank you but I do it exactly the same in a different model/controller and everything works fine there. The user is being sent to the method I don't need to do where. I put dd($request) first thing in the method, it shows me the request with all the fields and the correct values.

Comment: did you try `DB::table('users')` ? If that works, there must be something wrong in either your eloquent code or the eloquent core code. Please try using Query builder for checking.

Comment: Sorry, but where do I need to use DB::table('users') and why? The thing is this is working fine with other controllers I have. I changed it all to send an $id to the method instead of $user, and do findOrFail etc. I just need to understand why this code does not work when it works in other places

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't understand right away what you mean on your previous comment. So it works but not on that controller only. I thought it was not really working at all so I said used Query builder instead of Eloquent to check if it was Eloquent's fault.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I appreciate it